# Youtube API (SDK PHP) get list video user

Tags: youtube-data-api

It is possible to obtain the list of channels of a user that logs into my system (PHP SDK) with the total number of followers.
I also need the list of videos of the channel, with all the engagement.

Thank you very much,

Comment: What is your problem then?

Comment: Sory, its a question.

Comment: For me it looks like statement... And I don't see any problem stated in your post